# RegExp in FireFox 4-5b

Tags: javascript, regex, firefox

Why this regular expression does not work in FF? `/^\#q=(.*){1,50}\&type=([a-zA-Z]{5})\&offset=([0-9]{1,8})$/`

In all browsers exept FF it work good.Thanks

Comment: Why is `#` and `&` escaped? Why `(.*){1,50}` instead of something like `.{1,50}`?

Comment: Please provide more info about how it does not work

Comment: @alex if # and & are not escaped it doesn't worked too

Comment: @denysonique, function match with this expression return null

Comment: Please provide a sample string that should match and doesn't.

Comment: @jfriend00  
match -  `#q=some-long-word&type=image&offset=500`

doesn't - `#q=some-word-up50chars&type=blahblah&offset=notnumber`

Comment: This bit seems odd-

(.*){1,50}

Match between 1 and 50 repetitions of either no character or any number of any character except newline.

What is that about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is the `(.*)` at the beginning. I think, in effect, it is grabbing everything after the `#q=`, leaving nothing in the string left to find the rest of the expression. I would have thought all browsers would have interpreted the regex identically, but I guess not.

Try using something non-greedy

```
 (.*?)
```

or just use the bounds operator

```
 (.{1,50})
```

You probably do not need to use both.

Comment: Now array with matches contents only the first char from `#q=`

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 5 reports the regular expression is too complex in the debug console.  I think the problem is caused by this part which is a bit ambiguous.  It's 1-50 occurrences of however many characters you want to match.  Much better to change it as alex suggested:

```
(.*){1,50}
```

Chrome actually hangs trying to match the second string.

Anyway, you can fix the regular expression by changing it to this (which I think does what you want):

```
/^#q=(.){1,50}&type=([a-zA-Z]{5})&offset=([0-9]{1,8})$/
```

You can test it or try things out here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/wUHKV/

Comment: But 

`var data = hash.match(/^\#q=(.){1,50}\&type=([a-zA-Z]{5})\&offset=([0-9]{1,8})$/);`
 data[1] return first char from (.){1,50}.How get all word?

Comment: Please try to explain better.  There are multiple matches in the match array (four different ones).  What exact part of the input string are you trying to match or capture in the results?  You have not explained that so we have no idea.  You only asked for a regex which matched your whole sample which we have now provided.  If you want something different, please explain.